# Cannot parse NSString to NSURL with two # or more

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have application to make automatic phone call using phone card. As a result, I need to parse telephone number to nsurl to make phone call like this.

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://18005333333,,,1#,,,421#,,,959538988"];
[myApp openURL:telURL];
```

I notice that if there is more than 1 #, I can't parse to NSURL. It always return me nil. May I know how to parse to NSURL if I need to have more than 1 #?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can require iOS 7.0 or later, then I recommend that you use [`NSURLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html):

```
NSURLComponents* components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
components.scheme = @"tel";
components.host = @"18005333333,,,1#,,,421#,,,959538788";
NSURL* telURL = components.URL;
[myApp openURL:telURL];
```

Otherwise, you may need to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` to forcibly percent-escape the "#" characters. It's not really correct to use that function on whole URLs rather than components, but if you're only going to be using it on these sorts of URLs with no other components than the scheme and the phone number, it should work.

Comment: It is perfect. Thanks Ken Thomases

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need to use NSMutableURLRequest instead of openURL, and add parameters to it separately.

**EDIT:**
try this

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:@"tel://18005333333"];
    [request setValue:@"1#" forHTTPHeaderField:@",,,"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
```

Comment: May I know how to use?

Comment: It only call the "18005333333" and doesn't call for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the # in the phone number string if it really does not matter to make a phone call.like below

```
NSString *phoneString=@"18005333333,,,1#,,,421#,,,959538788";

NSString *phonenumberstring = [phoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];

NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",[phonenumberstring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]]];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *noAccess=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [noAccess show];
    }
```

(OR)

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:18005333333,,,1#,,,421#,,,959538788"];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: I need to have # because I am doing for prepaid phone card application.